# Cannot initialize json object with Data loaded from a json file

Tags: json, swift, decodable

I'm trying to create a simple app where the data is loaded from json files.

The name of my json file is:

summary.json

it contains the following:

```
{
  "name": "Octavio", 
  "lastName": "Rojas",
  "email": "octavio.rojas@globant.com",
  "phone": "5581723801",
  "degree": "Bachelors degree in international business and trade",
  "summary": "I just turned two years old in Globant on April 3rd 2019, I’ve been working with Disney for all this time in different areas of their parks app like resort reservations, profile and payment methods, geolocation services  and itinerary information during my time here I’ve been working on sustainment, increasing code coverage, automation, analytics, developing tests, doing refactors and developing critical components for the frameworks I’ve been assigned to. I’ve worked with all kinds of computers since childhood, I’ve also participated in different activities related with computer science and information technologies, like database development, technical support, unix systems administration, web development, flash development and iOS development."
}
```

I'm trying to read it using this function:

```
func loadJson() {
    do {
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "summary", withExtension: "json") else {
            return
        }
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let jsonData = try decoder.decode(Person.self, from: data)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

my struct looks like this:

```
struct Person: Encodable {
    let name: String
    let lastName: String
    let email: String
    let phone: String
    let degree: String
    let summary: String
}
```

but every time I try to Decode the data with

```
let jsonData = try decoder.decode(Person.self, from: data)
```

I'm getting this error:

```
 dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Badly formed object around character 88." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Badly formed object around character 88.})))
```

if instead of trying to load the json file I place it inside my class like this:

```
    let data = """
{
  "name": "Octavio",
  "lastName": "Rojas",
  "email": "octavio.rojas@globant.com"
  "phone": "5581723801"
  "degree": "Bachelors degree in international business and trade"
  "summary": "I just turned two years old in Globant on April 3rd 2019, I’ve been working with Disney for all this time in different areas of their parks app like resort reservations, profile and payment methods, geolocation services  and itinerary information during my time here I’ve been working on sustainment, increasing code coverage, automation, analytics, developing tests, doing refactors and developing critical components for the frameworks I’ve been assigned to. I’ve worked with all kinds of computers since childhood, I’ve also participated in different activities related with computer science and information technologies, like database development, technical support, unix systems administration, web development, flash development and iOS development."
}""".data(using: .utf8)
```

Then it works, why is this and what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show the actual content of your `summary.json`. Put `print(data[..<100] as NSData)` before the line `let decoder = ...`, and show while result. There's something wrong _around character 88_ in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json has missing `,` corrected here

```
{
    "name": "Octavio",
    "lastName": "Rojas",
    "email": "octavio.rojas@globant.com",
    "phone": "5581723801",
    "degree": "Bachelors degree in international business and trade",
    "summary": "I just turned two years old in Globant on April 3rd 2019, I’ve been working with Disney for all this time in different areas of their parks app like resort reservations, profile and payment methods, geolocation services and itinerary information during my time here I’ve been working on sustainment, increasing code coverage, automation, analytics, developing tests, doing refactors and developing critical components for the frameworks I’ve been assigned to. I’ve worked with all kinds of computers since childhood, I’ve also participated in different activities related with computer science and information technologies, like database development, technical support, unix systems administration, web development, flash development and iOS development."
}
```

---

```
struct Person: Codable {
    let name, lastName, email, phone,degree, summary: String 
}
```

---

```
let per = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Person.self, from: data)
print(per)
```

Comment: I did just like you said but I'm still getting the error. 

Thread 1: Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Swift.DecodingError.dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Badly formed object around character 88." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Badly formed object around character 88.})))

Comment: you missed `,` after `"email": "octavio.rojas@globant.com"`

Answer (score 0):

Embedded JSON in Swift needs to use [] instead of {}

```
[
    "name": "Octavio",
    "lastName": "Rojas",
    "email": "octavio.rojas@globant.com",
    "phone": "5581723801",
    "degree": "Bachelors degree in international business and trade",
    "summary": "I just turned two years old in Globant on April 3rd 2019, I’ve been working with Disney for all this time in different areas of their parks app like resort reservations, profile and payment methods, geolocation services and itinerary information during my time here I’ve been working on sustainment, increasing code coverage, automation, analytics, developing tests, doing refactors and developing critical components for the frameworks I’ve been assigned to. I’ve worked with all kinds of computers since childhood, I’ve also participated in different activities related with computer science and information technologies, like database development, technical support, unix systems administration, web development, flash development and iOS development."
]
```